# whats wrong with this code?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the current GPS location of the mobile. I am using emulator I have given the position to the emulator using DDMS but I am getting nothing in the screen also I don't get any errors.

```
public class getitright extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LocationManager lm=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll=new LocationListener(){
        public void onLocationChanged(Location l)
        {
            go(l);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}
    public void go(Location l){ 
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv.setText(""+l.getLatitude());
    }


}
```

Comment: I recommend you to be more descriptive in your title. Something such as "Problem with GPS and emulator in android". You will get more answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Put some log messages in for a start.

But secondly. You shouldn't declare your TextView or your LocationListener to be local variables like that. Those should both be member variables. By declaring your locationlistener like that, you lose your reference to it. That could be the problem, but if it's not, you're still unable to remove the locationlistener from the manager because you don't have a reference.

Are you sure your textview is even showing at all? Try setting it to something static in `onCreate` just to make sure

Also add an `@Override` statement to

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location l)
    {
        go(l);
    }
```

Just to be 100% sure you're actually overriding the method.